# Grouping and Grep-ing Specific Lines from a variable (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I have a PHP variable that holds similar data:

```
$var = "
Name: Tom
Age: 26
Location: London

Name: Mike
Age: 28
Location: New York

Name: Sunny
Age: 24
Location: Tokyo";
```

I'd like to extract only the locations, and store them in Array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => London
    [1] => New York
    [2] => Tokyo
)
```

For now, with my simple experience with PHP I'm getting this done using "*LOL, Don't Laugh..*":

```
$location = array_merge(preg_replace('/^Location: /','',preg_grep('/^Location: /',explode("\n", $var))));
```

But I believe, there would be a way better process (maybe with `preg_split`) to achieve that faster, wiser and with maybe less system over-load.

Kindly, advise..
Thanks in advance.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/Location: (.+)/', $var, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

That works because the dot doesn't match new line characters, by default.

Comment: Hello @rambo-coder, Thanks a lot for the answer.. Would it be better if I used the ^ in the regex to be like: `preg_match_all('/^Location: (.+)/', $var, $m);` Do you think this would be better to make sure Location starts the line?! Again Thanks Alot.